# Retornar lista de arquivos contidas em uma pagina web

Tags: json, array, node.js

Preciso passar o link de uma pagina pra um programa em node js, e ela me retornar todos os nomes dos arquivos .bz2 que contém nela.A pagina seria essa da imagem.

[image: Imagem com os arquivos que preciso]

Seria algo do tipo:

```
    request('https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ptwiki/20190801/).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
});
```

e a resposta que preciso seria

```
[
ptwiki-20190801-pages-articles-multistream1.xml-p220p95098.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index1.txt-p220p95098.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream2.xml-p95101p442463.bz2 ,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index2.txt-p95101p442463.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-pages-articles-multistream3.xml-p442475p1428483.bz2 ,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index3.txt-p442475p1428483.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream4.xml-p1428492p2522162.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index4.txt-p1428492p2522162.bz2,
ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream5.xml-p2522163p4022163.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index5.txt-p2522163p4022163.bz2 ,

ptwiki-20190801-pages-articles-multistream5.xml-p4022163p4362684.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index5.txt-p4022163p4362684.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-pages-articles-multistream6.xml-p4362698p5862698.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index6.txt-p4362698p5862698.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-pages-articles-multistream6.xml-p5862698p6052937.bz2,

ptwiki-20190801-páginas-artigos-multistream-index6.txt-p5862698p6052937.bz2    ]
```

Assim como array ou poderia ser como json ,isso usando node js,busquei na internet mas não encontrei nada a respeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, como você listou apenas o bz2, coloquei um filtro para mostrar somente ele. Entretanto, vi que não listou todos, porém não fiz esse filtro, já que não especificou se somente precisava de uma determinada data ou de todos. (mas também não é tão difícil fazer)

```
( async () => {
    const cheerio = require('cheerio')
    const request = require('request')

  request('https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ptwiki/20190801/', (error, response, body) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(body)

      $('a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().includes('.bz2')) {
            console.log($(this).text())
        }
      })
  })

})()
```

Apenas para explicar:

```
( () => {
// Isso é uma função auto executável, por isso ao rodar, já irá funcionar.
// Adeque o código que está aqui dentro da forma como você precisar.
})()
```

`request` é necessário para pegar o html da página

`cheerio` é necessário para manipular o html de uma maneira mais fácil, igual como se faz com `JQuery`.

Comment: Agradeço,funcionou corretamente,muito bom , obrigado

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida, posta ai.

Comment: Muito obrigado ,pode deixar